# Including a Python Library (suds) in a portable way

Tags: python, import, suds

I'm using suds (brilliant library, btw), and I'd like to make it portable (so that everyone who uses the code that relies on it, can just checkout the files and run it).

I have tracked down 'suds-0.4-py2.6.egg' (in python/lib/site-packages), and put it in with my files, and I've tried:

```
import path.to.egg.file.suds
from path.to.egg.file.suds import *
import path.to.egg.file.suds-0.4-py2.6
```

The first two complain that suds doesn't exist, and the last one has invalid syntax.

In the __init__.py file, I have:

```
__all__ = [ "FileOne" ,
            "FileTwo",
      "suds-0.4-py2.6"]
```

and have previously tried

```
__all__ = [ "FileOne" ,
            "FileTwo",
      "suds"]
```

but neither work.

Is this the right way of going about it? If so, how can I get my imports to work. If not, how else can I achieve the same result?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't to be used for users, this is for testing, and it'd just be easier to include suds with my files then it would to install it on the test machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add your egg file to `sys.path`, like this:

```
import sys
# insert at 0 instead of appending to end to take precedence 
# over system-installed suds (if there is one).
sys.path.insert(0, "suds-0.4-py2.6.egg")
import suds
```

Answer (score 1):

`.egg` files are zipped archives; hence you cannot directly import them as you have discovered.

The easy way is to simply unzip the archive, and then copy the `suds` directory to your application's source code directory. Since Python will stop at the first module it discovers; your local copy of suds will be used even if it is not installed globally for Python.

One step up from that, is to add the `egg` to your path by appending it to `sys.path`.

However, the proper way would be to [package your application](http://guide.python-distribute.org/) for distribution; or provide a [requirements file](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) that lets other people know what external packages your program depends on.

Comment: This is not true, you can import them directly. See my answer below. It is not a good and/or recommended practice to distribute software this way, but whatever...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing it; but as you mentioned there are other/better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I distribute my program with a `requirements.txt` file that contain all dependencies and their version.
The users can then install these libraries with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I don't think including `eggs` with your code is a good idea, what if the user use python2.7 instead of python2.6

More info about requirement file: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html